# Problems with JS pulling non-existent video files from the server

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble with this site: http://metro-structure.com

It was designed/developed by somebody else and I was asked to come in and help sort through these issues. Problem is, I'm not up to par on JS development so I'm totally lost. Here's what's going on:

If you click on the "video" thumbnail of the gallery that shows on load, a video pops up. Perfect. Now try clicking "magnolia 2" and then click the "video" thumbnail. No video, just an image. If you click to another listing and then back to "magnolia 2" the video appears normally.

Now, if you click the last thumbnail of the other galleries that do not have videos, it will still try to pull up the non-existent videos, of course resulting in an error message.

I believe the JS below is basically telling the browser to pull up a video if one is hosted in the respective "/videos/" folder on the server. I've triple checked and made sure the file structure is perfect, so that's not the issue:

Here are the gallery's parameters:

```
controllers.Gallery = {
        cfg: {
            path: './gallery/',
            max: 12,
            duration: 300,
            video: {
                width: 640,
                height: 480
            },
            dir: {
                sm: '/Thumbs/',
                med: '/228x150/',
                lrg: '/600x400/',
                video: '/video/'
            }
        },
```

and here is the code that I believe is flawed:

```
load: function ($set, gallery) {
            var _this = this;
            _this.$sets.removeClass('active');
            $set.addClass('active');

            if (!_this.$thumbs.find('.' + gallery).length > 0) {
                var $ul = $('<ul class="' + gallery + ' clear"></ul>').appendTo(_this.$thumbs);
                for (var i = 1, j = _this.cfg.max; i <= j; i++) {
                    $('<li><img src="' + _this.cfg.path + gallery + _this.cfg.dir.sm + i + '.jpg' + '"></li>').on('click', function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if ($this.hasClass('video')) {
                            _this.showVideo($this);
                        } else { _this.showThumb($this); }
                    }).attr({
                        'data-med-src': _this.cfg.path + gallery + _this.cfg.dir.med + i + '.jpg',
                        'data-lrg-src': _this.cfg.path + gallery + _this.cfg.dir.lrg + i + '.jpg'
                    }).appendTo($ul);
                }
            }
            _this.cleanup(_this.$thumbs.find('.' + gallery + ' li'));
            _this.$thumbs.find('.' + gallery + ' li:last').attr({
                'data-video-src':  _this.cfg.path + gallery + _this.cfg.dir.video + gallery
            }).addClass('video');
            _this.$thumbs.find('ul').hide().removeClass('active');
            _this.$thumbs.find('.' + gallery).show().addClass('active');
            _this.showThumb(_this.$thumbs.find('.active li:first'));
        },
```

The full .js file can be seen here: http://metro-structure.com/js/base.js

I appreciate any advice or pointers I can use to get this sorted. Thanks so much!

Comment: As a small addition, the video in Boylston 2's gallery is working. In addition, the video in the Magnolia 2's gallery works when you click Magnolia 2 a second time...

Comment: Here's what I've figured out. There are 12 images added every time to the gallery with the last one defaulting to a video. With many of the other galleries, you see they don't have videos as their last icon, and clicking them will show an error. With the Magnolia 2's gallery, there are missing image files, so 7-12 never get loaded. The 12th would be the video, but since it doesn't exist, it doesn't show up. However the second time you click to view Magnolia 2's gallery, it doesn't create those elements again, but does still apply the information needed to show the video on the last element.

Comment: So the real question how you'll want to go about fixing this. Either you can change the last link for every gallery to be videos and add images to Magnolia 2's gallery so that the video icon appears 12th, or you can write new code that contains data to load each gallery differently. This can be done with ajax, a javascript object loaded with the page that contains this data, or make the video be separate from the list of images so that there's no chance it could be an image or vice versa and the video will just fail to appear if its thumbnail doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pluto that makes a ton of sense. thanks so much for your help so far! at least now I have some idea of why this is occurring :)